# iphone use of the following function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

i am a beginner in iphone programming ,i found the following code on a site but dont know the function of the code can anyone please explain the function of the code. according to my view it might be the code for picking a file from a location to upload it onto server. is this so?

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];  

[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];  

[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];  

[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it makes use of the [ASIHTTPRequest framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's part of a setup to make a http post request setting some parameters.

Comment: @ Nick weaver what the setpostvalue is doing in the above function?

Comment: @Junior Bill gates it does set a post parameter to the request with a given value and a given name.

Answer (score 0):

you are right!

this code will execute an HTTP POST with two form data fields and a file to upload.

Comment: nothing... HTTP has the POST verb, TCP is the layer that HTTP runs above... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ sergio i want to make a client server application, but i dont have much knowledge of socket programming in objective c,and m using TCP protocol .can  u plz suggest some idea about it.

Comment: can above code will help me uploading a file from the desktop to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. It might help you :

[ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Comment: @nitish what the setpost value will do ?

Comment: setPostValue is used to specify each parameter of web method you are using.

Comment: @ nitish can i comment the both lines containg setpostvalue if i only want to pick a file from a particular location?

Comment: I don't think so. In those two lines you are setting parameters. If you comment those lines, those parameters will be set to "nil". Things won't work this way.

Comment: @ nitish what parameters are being set in those two lines?

Comment: Parameters of the web method you use in your web service. Like in this case parameters are first_name, last_name.

Comment: You should consider looking this example : [Use of setPost](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

These values might be used to pass as a parameter to some HTTP POST Request.